# Conditional default value based on sequence

Tags: postgresql, sequence

There is a PG table `example` with two fk columns `table_a_id`, `table_b_id` and `position::int` column. It's guaranteed there will be only one column filled `table_a_id` or `table_b_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE table_a(
   id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE table_b(
   id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

CREATE TABLE example(
   table_a_id INT,
   table_b_id INT,
   position INT,
   CONSTRAINT fk_table_a
      FOREIGN KEY(table_a_id) 
          REFERENCES table_a(id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_table_b
      FOREIGN KEY(table_b_id) 
          REFERENCES table_a(id)
);
```

I want `position` column to be incremented every time new record is being created. But value for incrementing must be picked based on which column is currently filled.
I considered creating two sequences owned by `table_a_id` and `table_b_id` but I have no guess how to set default value for `position` based on these sequences.
Probably it'd be something like

```
CREATE SEQUENCE serial_a OWNED BY example.table_a_id;
CREATE SEQUENCE serial_b OWNED BY example.table_b_id;

ALTER TABLE example ALTER COLUMN position SET DEFAULT 
  nextval('serial_a' IF table_a_id IS NOT NULL) ||  
  nextval('serial_b' IF table_b_id IS NOT NULL);
```

but I dont know how to express it correcly.

Maybe I'm looking in the wrong direction. The result should be like that:

| table_a_id | table_a_id | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 1 |
| 2 |  | 2 |
|  | 1 | 1 |
|  | 2 | 2 |
|  | 3 | 3 |
| 3 |  | 3 |
| 4 |  | 4 |
|  | 4 | 4 |

Comment: Not possible. You need a trigger for that

Answer (score 0):

From a data model perspective this seems a bit wierd, but perhaps you have good reasons for it. From your example it appears as if one of the columns is always null and the other one has a value. You can then add a generated column that picks its value from the non-null column:

```
CREATE TABLE example(
   table_a_id INT,
   table_b_id INT,
   position INT generated always as ( least(table_a_id, table_b_id)) stored ,
   CONSTRAINT fk_table_a
      FOREIGN KEY(table_a_id) 
          REFERENCES table_a(id),
   CONSTRAINT fk_table_b
      FOREIGN KEY(table_b_id) 
          REFERENCES table_a(id)
);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4a977716bc9308209fb893a6a45d0d10)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't fit to my particular case since `table_*_id` is actually UUID. ID::int was introduced for simplification sake.

Comment: I suggest you make a new question without oversimplifications